# Why does casting PSCustomObjects to custom type with DateTime in PowerShell fails?

Tags: powershell, types, casting

I would like to cast PSCustomObjects to custom types. Casting does work for simple types, but it doesn't work if I use e.g. DateTime within the type definition. Casting from a HashTable to custom type does work. Why does casting from PSCustomObject does not work as expected?

Here's an example:

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
public struct Test {
    public DateTime date;
}
"@

$Properties = @{date=(Get-Date)}
$CustomObject = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $Properties

# Returns correct date:
$TestObjectCastFromProperties = [Test]$Properties
$TestObjectCastFromProperties
$TestObjectCastFromProperties.GetType()

# Returns wrong date
$TestObjectCastFromCustomObject = [Test]$CustomObject
$TestObjectCastFromCustomObject
$TestObjectCastFromCustomObject.GetType()
```

Comment: `$Properties = @{date=(Get-Date).PSObject.BaseObject}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell you why this doesn't work. Even the explicit conversion fails:

```
[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertPSObjectToType(
    $CustomObject, [test], $true, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture, $false)
```

**Output:**

```
date               
----               
01.01.0001 00:00:00
```

---

However, you could use a handcrafted function to convert a `PSCustomObject` to a `Type`:

```
function Cast-CustomObject
{
    Param
    (
        [PsCustomObject]$obj,
        [Type]$castType
    )
    $properties = ($obj.PSObject.Properties | % { @{$_.Name = $_.Value}})
    [System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo($properties, $castType)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Cast-CustomObject -obj $CustomObject -castType ([Test])
```

**Output:**

```
date               
----               
06.07.2016 08:52:01
```